# Uploading a user picture with json:api

Tags: 9

I'm trying to craft a curl request to upload an image to the user_picture field on a user entity using json:api.

The [documentation](https://www.drupal.org/docs/core-modules-and-themes/core-modules/jsonapi-module/file-uploads) is, umm, minimal, but I've used it as a starting point and I have this:

```
curl -s -X POST -b cookie.txt \
    --header "Accept: application/vnd.api+json" \
    --header "Content-type: application/octet-stream" \
    --header "X-CSRF-Token: $TOKEN" \
    --header "Content-Disposition: file: filename=test.jpg" \
    --data-binary "@test.jpg" \
    http://localhost/jsonapi/user/user/$UUID/user_picture
```

The response for this is "`No route found that matches \"Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\"`".

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As soon as I posted this I realised my issue, `Content-type` instead of `Content-Type`, duh!